# How do I find a the value of a td in a specific tr

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, xpath, capybara

I am have a rails app that I am writing cucumber test for.  I am trying to get a number out of specific row so I can assert against it.  I have a table that looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="kids">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Balance</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr data-link="/kids/2">
      <td>Jason</td>
      <td>
        <span>$</span>
        <span class="money">1.00</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-link="/kids/3">
      <td>Neely</td>
      <td>
        <span>$</span>
        <span class="money">0.50</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to select a td that has a specific name, and then get the balance from the span in the following td.  I am sure there is a way to do this with Xpath, but I cannot figure it out.  Any help would be great.

Comment: `I need to select a td that has a specific name` — I can't see a TD with a name attribute. That is going to make getting it by name difficult.

Comment: OP means the text in the first TD. Aka person's name.

Comment: It isnt a name attribute, it is a td with a name in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for XPath so here it is:

```
//td[preceding-sibling::td[text()='Neely']]/span[@class='money']
```

Note that XPathes aren't very readable and it may be better to use Capybara's ruby methods instead:

```
tr = find('tr', text: 'Neely')
tr.find('.money').text
```